# how to make a jquery "$.post" request synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’ve been googling this and avoiding this error in my bug fix list for a long time now, but I’ve finally reached the end of the list, the last of which I have to make a function return true/false to state whether the validation has succeeded or not.

I'm using ajax to compare certain fields with those that are already in the db and by default the `$.post()` method does it's operations asynchronously.

I’m setting a variable inside the call `onSuccess` and the calling method doesn't get a response because of this, so all my js/jquery fails on pageLoad... I would prefer if I could still keep using the `$.post` method.

Comment: Ah, you'll need to add a code sample to clarify this one.

Comment: Do not do this.  It will freeze the browser until the server replies.

Comment: @Neal, the reason this question is unique is because jQuery has multiple ways of calling a server page and I specifically wanted to know how to make a $.post request synchronous, not just a jQuery ajax request

Answer (score 226, accepted):

**jQuery < 1.8**

May I suggest that you use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.post()` as it's much more customizable.

If you are calling `$.post()`, e.g., like this:

```
$.post( url, data, success, dataType );
```

You could turn it into its `$.ajax()` equivalent:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false
});
```

Please note the `async:false` at the end of the `$.ajax()` parameter object.

Here you have a full detail of the `$.ajax()` parameters: [jQuery.ajax() – jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

---

**jQuery >=1.8 "async:false" deprecation notice**

jQuery >=1.8 won't block the UI during the http request, so we have to use a workaround to stop user interaction as long as the request is processed. For example:

- use a plugin e.g. [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/);
- manually add an overlay before calling `$.ajax()`, and then remove it when the AJAX `.done()` callback is called.

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448103/719247) for an example.

Answer (score 18):

If you want an synchronous request set the `async` property to `false` for the request. Check out the [jQuery AJAX Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 7):

From the Jquery docs: you specify the async option to be false to get a synchronous Ajax request. Then your callback can set some data before your mother function proceeds.

Here's what your code would look like if changed as suggested:

```
beforecreate: function(node,targetNode,type,to) {
    jQuery.ajax({
         url:    url,
         success: function(result) {
                      if(result.isOk == false)
                          alert(result.message);
                  },
         async:   false
    });          
}
```

this is because $.ajax is the only request type that you can set the asynchronousity for

Comment: This answer seems to be a copy of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/133327/3714134) answer.

Comment: @HugoZink It was definitely copied, but both of our answers were copied from the jQuery docs :-D