# Ajax is failing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why this Ajax script isnt working.

Heres the code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.edit_user', function(){
    console.log('submit');
    $.post
    (
      $(this).attr('action'),
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(data){
        console.log("data");
        console.log(data);
        $('#edit_first_name').val(data['first_name']);
      },
      "json"
    );
    return false;
  });
```

I have the `submit` show up in the console so I know the `.post` is called. I also know it makes it to the `return false` because the form never submits and redirects.

However, it never `console.log(data)`.

I'm pretty sure all this is because I'm forgetting something simple.

Comment: Probably the function returns `false` before receiving the response because `$.post` is asynchronous. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous

Comment: if you work in Chrome console, check the "Network" tab. Is ajax request there?

Comment: @enenen I tried this with `.ajax` (mind you I've actually never done it this way. So its probably wrong):

`$.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      async:false
    })
    return false;`

It still had the same results

Comment: @lvil if by ajax request you mean the result of the function called by the form, then yes, its there.

Comment: I bet $0.1 that your server doesn't set the `content-type` to **application/json**-.

Comment: @OneOfOne if it did I dont know how to check. Especially since I have a metric s#*t ton of ajax in the exact same format as above. So I know json is working at least in the rest of things

Comment: Check my example then with the fail handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `.fail()` callback and see if it returns, also make sure the server sends the json header properly or `$.post` will fail.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.edit_user', function(){
    console.log('submit');
    var jqXHR = $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(),
        function(data){
            console.log("data");
            console.log(data);
            $('#edit_first_name').val(data['first_name']);
        },
        "json"
    );
    jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error', textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
    return false;
});
```

If you're using PHP, make sure you have the correct header printed before any other output.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    ....code...
    echo json_encode(some_array);
```

Comment: Well, first off, I had forgotten about the `echo json_encode`. I needed that regardless of this problem but it didnt fix it. I tried your suggestion and it gave me this error: `error parsererror SyntaxError {}` However, it doesnt say where the error is. It just references the line where it was thrown.

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with your json, edit your question and paste your json.

Comment: Ok, so I'm not sure where the whole problem was. I think it was a combination of a lot of small things that I was overlooking. I had forgotten about the `header('Content-type: application/json');` and the `echo json_encode(some_array);`. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The function you have defined is for the success callback. Make sure your current post is returning a successful response from the server. Or convert the `.post()` call to a `.ajax()` call and define the failure calback

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
$(document).on('submit', '.edit_user', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log('submit');
$.post
(
  $(this).attr('action'),
  $(this).serialize(),
  function(data){
    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);
    $('#edit_first_name').val(data['first_name']);
  },
  "json"
);
return false;
});
```

Use preventDefault function to prevent default behaviour of submit.
Also .edit_user should be the class of the form element

Answer (score -1):

Does your javascript logger return you something ?