# How to stop jquery ajax page reload on success or failure

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am facing a problem in ajax jquery on success. My whole jsp reload on ajax success even after putting return false. How to prevent page reloading.

```
function AjaxCall(category){

var formValue = $('#TP').serialize();
$.post('saveIndvQuestionnaire.jsp?'+formValue+'&category='+category,
//$.post('callPage.jsp',
        function(data) {
    return false;
});
}
```

I am calling AjaxCall function from input type image

```
<input id="test" type="image" onclick="javascript:AjaxCall('Test');" src="../images/v10/larrow.png">
```

I am not sure I read somewhere type images makes two calls onclick.

Thanks.

Comment: what triggers the call? im guessing just move the `return` to outside the callback

Comment: if you're doing something like a "submit" button, you'll need to use `e.preventDefault()` to keep the default action from happening

Comment: @tymeJV I am calling above function onclick

Comment: @pise onclick of what?

Comment: @tymeJV `<input id="test" type="image" onclick="javascript:AjaxCall('Test');" src="../images/v10/larrow.png">`

Comment: Your `return false;` should be the last statement of your function not of `$.post`. Like: `$.post('...', function(data){ ... }); return false;`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent even I tried with putting return false on the last statement but still it reloads the page.

Comment: Try to use  $.ajax() instead of $.post() as it's much more customizable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous

Comment: @Phx I tried below code but then also same error. Is there something with type = 'image' `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url:'saveIndvQuestionnaire.jsp?'+formValue+'&category='+category, success :function(data){},async:false});`

Comment: async should be true. Can you use firebug to see the error? (javascript error I mean)

Comment: @Phx there is no error in console I used firebug

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is the behavior of input type image.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input
Try to use e.preventDefault() in your function and no Submit should be done.

```
$( "#test" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
var formValue = $('#TP').serialize();
$.post('saveIndvQuestionnaire.jsp?'+formValue+'&category='+category,
        function(data) {
    return false;
});

});
```

Exmple

http://jsfiddle.net/HBeVv/10/

You can use another html control to achieve this like a href with a Image:

```
<a href="#" onClick="alert('Hello World!')"><img title="The Link" /></a>
```

Comment: I used href instead of input type image and now my code is working fine.. Thaks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also Like this

```
$('YourForm').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   formdata=$(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: formdata
      }).done(function(data){
  //do something
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input id="test" type="image" onclick="return javascript:AjaxCall('Test');" src="../images/v10/larrow.png">
```

You should get "return" the response onclick.