# How can i async false in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have apply jQuery ajax function like this please help me how can i async false in this code

```
$.post(base_url+"search/questionBox/"+finalTopic+"/"+finalCountry+'/'+findSearchText+'/'+ID,function(data){
  if (data != "") {
     $(".lazy_loading_ul").append(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Um, why? `async:false` is bad...

Comment: I don't see why you would wanna do that but it's still a duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous

Answer (score 4):

`$.post` is shorthand for `$.ajax` with the method set to `POST`. So you might as well do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url+ 'search/questionBox/'+finalTopic+'/'+
                                          finalCountry+'/'+findSearchText+'/'+ID
    async: false,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(data){
    if(data){
        $(".lazy_loading_ul").append(data);
    }
});
```

Though I advise against `async: false` in the first place. As of jQuery 1.8, the `async` option is deprecated.

Don't use it because it defeats the purpose of using AJAX in the first place.