# Make Parallel Ajax requests return response in order

Tags: php, jquery

i want to make multiple ajax requests using jQuery that appends table rows into a table but i want their response in order

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    //variables tempString, start_value updated here after every loop iteration

    $.post(
        'results.php',
        {start_value:start_value,tempString:tempString},
        function(data3){
            // alert(data3);
            $('#data_table tbody tr:last').after(data3);
        }
    );

}
```

**results.php** returns a set of table rows with every request but they dont append to the table in the right order.

how do I make the next ajax requests wait till the first ones are finished?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zhjx89Lf/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous

Comment: chrome gives a warning on using synchronous ajax saying that it can hinder with user experience. Infact, i tried it before posting this question, but it would freeze my page till all the responses were not received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to synchronus call and in your case it call asynchronously thats why it not append in right order.

```
function doAsyncCall(i) {
    if (i < 5) {
       $.post(
        'results.php',
        {start_value:start_value,tempString:tempString},
        function(data3){
            $('#data_table tbody tr:last').after(data3);
            doAsyncCall(i+1);
        }
      );
    }
}

doAsyncCall(0);
```