# Variable value changing for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I know that the answer to this question is probably obvious, but I seem to be stuck, so I decided to ask a question.

Inside my jQuery `$(document).ready` function, I have created a variable called `logged`. I have set it up like this: `var logged = 0;`

Next I have a post block of code, which, based on the returned data will set the `logged` variable to `1` or not change it.

```
$.post("url/script.php",
function(d, s){
    if (s) {
        if (d == "1") {
            logged = 1;
        }
        if (d == "0") {
            //Do stuff
        }
    } else {
        //Do other stuff
    }
    console.log(logged); //Prints 1
});
```

Underneath that I have an `if` statement which checks to see if logged is `1` or not, but a `console.log` command above reveals that the `logged` variable has reset to `0`:

```
console.log(logged); //Prints 0

if (logged == 1) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not reset, it's being set in an asychronous call - and your `if` logic is running before the call is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is because `$.post()` is an asynchronous function. Meaning, your Javascript continues to run while `$.post()` is still running. Your JS does not wait for it to return. So, by the time your console logs `logged` it is still set to `0`

So in fact, it is not reset, it just has not yet been set to `1`

To combat this you can set a variable to your post statement and check if it is done.

```
  var posting = $.post( url, function() );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
    //do something when complete
  });
```

you can read more about this in jQuery's API - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

You should also take a look at this question which addresses making `$.post()` a synchronous call [how to make a jquery "$.post" request synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that was really helpful, Adjit.