# Jquery - Post beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to post data before unload (just before visitor closes page). Unload may vary on different browsers, so I have done this following script;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var runme = true;

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    if(runme){

if ($("#benyaziyormuyum").val()=="evet") {

$.post("yazmabirak.php", {
karsidaki: "exited",
});

}
        runme=false;
    }

});

$(window).unload(function () {
    if(runme){

$.post("yazmabirak.php", {
karsidaki: "exited",
});
        runme=false;
    }
});
```

It works on all browsers, except Chrome. My question is, which before unload function should be used to make it work on Chrome ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it isn't getting called?

$.post is an asynchronous call and you have nothing that prevents the browser from continuing on after the $.post().

You need to make this synchronous by using $.ajax() where you can set async: false

[how to make a jquery "$.post" request synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Nope, suprisingly if you close the chrome windows, it doesnt work. But if you go another page (without close) it works.

Comment: So you set a break point, closed the window, and never hit the breakpoint.  I've used before unload multiple times to prevent closing the window and it always works for me.  I still thing your problem is one of syncronicity

Comment: Maybe thats Chrome's bug. If you add alert(); it may work, but there is a problem when sending post before visitor close the window. Did your script also posts ?