# Trying to get addMethod in jquery validation to work. console.log shows the proper response, but it always fails validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using data attributes for jQuery Validation plugin. I need to use the "remote" validation function, however, I need to modify the data being sent to the remote location depending on the form it is used on. I want to use data attributes and not create a `<script>` call for each form.

I created a custom `$.validator.addMethod` to handle this, but every time I run it, the form comes back like it is returning `false`. I added a call to `console.log()` to make sure that the data is returning either `true` or `false` based on the remote script and it is. It returns `true` when it should and `false` when it should.

Here is my custom addMethod:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dupcheck", function(value,element){
    var method = element.getAttribute("data-method");
    var data = { "dupcheckv" : value, "dupcheckm" : method };
    $.post( "duplicate-check.php", data).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    });
});
```

I did take a look at [how to make a jquery “$.post” request synchronous [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821380/how-to-make-a-jquery-post-request-synchronous)
, but `async:false` is deprecated so that doesn't help.

Comment: i doubt this one has async support but try returning $.post( ...

Comment: @joyBlanks so you’re saying put a return in front of $.post? `return $.post(`

Comment: No need to post answer in two places.  Below as an actual answer preferred.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by copying all of the `remote` function and put it in the `addMethod` call:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dupcheck", function(value, element, param, method){
    if ( this.optional( element ) ) {
        return "dependency-mismatch";
    }

    method = typeof method === "string" && method || "dupcheck";

    var previous = this.previousValue( element, method ),
        validator, data, optionDataString;

    if ( !this.settings.messages[ element.name ] ) {
        this.settings.messages[ element.name ] = {};
    }
    previous.originalMessage = previous.originalMessage || this.settings.messages[ element.name ][ method ];
    this.settings.messages[ element.name ][ method ] = previous.message;

    param = typeof param === "string" && { url: param } || param;
    optionDataString = $.param( $.extend( { data: value }, param.data ) );
    if ( previous.old === optionDataString ) {
        return previous.valid;
    }

    previous.old = optionDataString;
    validator = this;
    this.startRequest( element );
    data = {};
    data[ "dupcheckv" ] = value;
    data[ "dupcheckm" ] = element.getAttribute("data-method");
    $.ajax( $.extend( true, {
        mode: "abort",
        port: "validate" + element.name,
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        context: validator.currentForm,
        success: function( response ) {
            var valid = response === true || response === "true",
                errors, message, submitted;

            validator.settings.messages[ element.name ][ method ] = previous.originalMessage;
            if ( valid ) {
                submitted = validator.formSubmitted;
                validator.resetInternals();
                validator.toHide = validator.errorsFor( element );
                validator.formSubmitted = submitted;
                validator.successList.push( element );
                validator.invalid[ element.name ] = false;
                validator.showErrors();
            } else {
                errors = {};
                message = response || validator.defaultMessage( element, { method: method, parameters: value } );
                errors[ element.name ] = previous.message = message;
                validator.invalid[ element.name ] = true;
                validator.showErrors( errors );
            }
            previous.valid = valid;
            validator.stopRequest( element, valid );
        }
    }, param ) );

    return "pending";
});
```